# What is the attitude to this problem?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to show that for ever $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ the following hold : $$
|1-z \bar{w}|^{2}+|z+w|^{2}=\left(1+|z|^{2}\right)\left(1+|w|^{2}\right)
$$

I am not sure if my approach here is true, I notice that I can mark $$z=a+bi$$ $$w=c+di$$ and than subtitude it in the above expression, but this seems too much algebra and I think this is not the point of the problem. (I am not even sure if that approach is true)

Comment: you may find it helpful to note that for any $\zeta\in\Bbb{C}$, $|\zeta|^2=\zeta\cdot \overline{\zeta}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're suggesting is right. And yes, it would involve some algebra. However, there is an identity you can use to solve it and the exercise seems to be an application of that identity. I'll provide that much and leave the rest to you. Use the fact that for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$.

Comment: thank you for that hint, I succeded thanks to that. :)